# PySpark Alternative to countItems(); performance issues

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We're working on a project where we extract dates, the source of a hyperlink, and the origin of a hyperlink.

The data looks like this:

`rddx.take(20)`

```python
[('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.equalvoice.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.equalvoice.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.equalvoice.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.equalvoice.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.thestar.com'),
 ('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'gettingtothegate.com'),
 ('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.snapdesign.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca')]
```

What we want is a result that would take the above and make it so:

```python
[(('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'), 13), (('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.equalvoice.ca'), 4), (('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.thestar.com'), 1), (('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'gettingtothegate.com'), 1), (('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.snapdesign.ca'), 1)]
```

i.e. a frequency of each unique occurrence of the date, source, and target. Of course, our real dataset is *very large*.

We have tried using `countbyValues()`, `countItems()`, but have failed at making any performance strides.

For reference, here is our full script but it depends on so many weird packages, that I suspect the `rddx` paste above will be more useful. :)

```python
import RecordLoader
from DFTransformations import *
from ExtractDomain import ExtractDomain
from ExtractLinks import ExtractLinks
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import re

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("siteLinkStructureByDate").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

df = RecordLoader.loadArchivesAsDF(path, sc, spark)
fdf = df.select(df['crawlDate'], df['url'], df['contentString'])
rdd = fdf.rdd
rddx = rdd.map (lambda r: (r.crawlDate, ExtractLinks(r.url, r.contentString)))\
 .flatMap(lambda r: map(lambda f: (r[0], ExtractDomain(f[0]), ExtractDomain(f[1])), r[1]))\
 .filter(lambda r: r[-1] != None)\
 .map(lambda r: (r[0], re.sub(r'^.*www.', '', r[1]), re.sub(r'^.*www.', '', r[2])))\
 .countByValue()

print([((x[0], x[1], x[2]), y) for x, y in rddx.items()])
```

What would you do to speed up the rddx sorting? Thanks so much in advance for your help and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shuold be very fast:

```
rddx = sc.parallelize([('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.equalvoice.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.equalvoice.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.equalvoice.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.equalvoice.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.thestar.com'),
 ('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'gettingtothegate.com'),
 ('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.snapdesign.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'),
 ('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca')])

print rddx.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).collect()
```

Result:

```
[(('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.equalvoice.ca'), 4), (('20091218', 'www.liberal.ca', 'www.liberal.ca'), 13), (('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.thestar.com'), 1), (('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'www.snapdesign.ca'), 1), (('20091218', 'www.equalvoice.ca', 'gettingtothegate.com'), 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks. When I run the above block, I get `File "<ipython-input-162-0b87a6a75d92>", line 22
    print rddx.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).collect()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: Are you running python 3? Maybe you need parentheses for print? For me it runs with no problems.

Comment: I ultimately got it running with `.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).collect()`, thanks. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

My initial instinct is to suggest you use the spark sql package, then you can simply do

```
sql_session.createDataFrame(rdd).groupby(col('crawlDate'), col('url'), col('contentString')).count()
```

If this is not available to you, reduceByKey seems like a likely next contender.